# Obtaining Raw Facebook Cookie Contents iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, cookies, ios4

I wanted to use Facebook to authenticate my iPhone client with my Google App Engine web server. The way I figured doing this would be the following:

1. Log in with facebook on the iPhone
2. Obtain the Facebook cookie (signed with my app's Secret Id)
3. Have the iPhone client send the cookie to my server
4. Verify the signature on the cookie from the server side (which also know's the app's Secret Id)

I have successfully done thiswith a javascript client that and a JSON RPC tool running on app engine, but I can' seem to get the raw Facebook cookie contents on the iPhone using the Facebook SDK (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). Using their sample code, I've set up a simple log in with Facebook iPhone client. If you look at Facebook.m it reads cookies as NSHttpCookie, but it lacks the information I am seeing from my javascript client.

I am not seeing this information:
access_token=
expires=
secret=
session_key=
sig=

I can at least obtain the access token, the other way to authenticate on my server, would be to accept the users access token and then make a request to facebook's graph api on the server side to verify that the access token is indeed for who the user claims to be user.

Any ideas on how to get the entire cookie on the iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is read up on `NSHTTPCookieStorage` and `NSHTTPCookie`.  Documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSHTTPCookie).

Here is some sample code on iterating through the cookies that your app has access to read/write:

```
for(NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies])
{
    // read and write from the CookieStorage
}
```

As the documentation points out, keep in mind that you only have access to *your* cookies and not any other app's, including Safari.app.